# Jquery previous closest one input based on data attribute

Tags: jquery

I am trying to find the value of an input closest, previous limited to one with data attribute value but dont know where is the issue

```
var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
var $closest_product = $row.prevAll('tr').first().find(":selected[data-producttype='Product']");
var $closerow = $closest_product.closest('tr');
var $cp_length = parseFloat($closerow.find('.length').val());
alert($cp_length);
```

The above code only works to find the value if result lies in just preceding first row but never returns the result if the result lies 2 or more rows up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried to change

```
var $closest_product = $row.prevAll('tr').first().
find(":selected[data-producttype='Product']");
```

into

```
var $closest_product = $row.prevAll('tr').
find(":selected[data-producttype='Product']");
```

It just looks like you select all previous tr and then the first one to find the one tr you're looking for instead of searching through all tr.

Without knowing the html just a guess: maybe closest selects the right tr

```
var $closest_product = $row.closest("tr:selected[data-producttype='Product']");
```